# Maven Package Success But Can't Find Some Jar In The WEB-INF/lib

Tags: maven, jar, package

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        </dependency>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <warName>${project.artifactId}</warName>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4</version>
                </plugin>
```

And then run "mvn package", all success and create an test.war.
But then I open test.war can't find some important jar.
These jar can find in local Maven Path,but can't package in the war.

Lack jar as follows:

```
spring-aop-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-beans-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-jms-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-webmvc-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar
```

Maven Debug Info

```
[DEBUG] Processing: spring-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar
[DEBUG] Processing: spring-beans-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar
[DEBUG] Processing: spring-context-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar
[DEBUG] Processing: spring-expression-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar
[DEBUG] Processing: spring-aop-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar
[DEBUG] Processing: aopalliance-1.0.jar
[DEBUG]  + WEB-INF/lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar has been copied.
[DEBUG] Processing: spring-context-support-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar
[DEBUG]  + WEB-INF/lib/spring-context-support-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar has been copied.
[DEBUG] Processing: aspectjrt-1.7.4.jar
[DEBUG]  + WEB-INF/lib/aspectjrt-1.7.4.jar has been copied.
[DEBUG] Processing: aspectjweaver-1.7.4.jar
[DEBUG]  + WEB-INF/lib/aspectjweaver-1.7.4.jar has been copied.
[DEBUG] Processing: hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.8.Final.jar
[DEBUG]  + WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.8.Final.jar has been copied.
[DEBUG] Processing: jboss-logging-3.1.0.GA.jar
[DEBUG]  + WEB-INF/lib/jboss-logging-3.1.0.GA.jar has been copied.
[DEBUG] Processing: hibernate-core-4.2.8.Final.jar
[DEBUG]  + WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-core-4.2.8.Final.jar has been copied.
[DEBUG] Processing: antlr-2.7.7.jar
[DEBUG]  + WEB-INF/lib/antlr-2.7.7.jar has been copied.
[DEBUG] Processing: javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar
[DEBUG]  + WEB-INF/lib/javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar has been copied.
[DEBUG] Processing: jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec-1.0.1.Final.jar
[DEBUG]  + WEB-INF/lib/jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec-1.0.1.Final.jar has been copied.
[DEBUG] Processing: hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar
[DEBUG]  + WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar has been copied.
[DEBUG] Processing: hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.2.Final.jar
[DEBUG]  + WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.2.Final.jar has been copied.
[DEBUG] Processing: hibernate-ehcache-4.2.8.Final.jar
[DEBUG]  + WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-ehcache-4.2.8.Final.jar has been copied.
[DEBUG] Processing: mybatis-3.2.3.jar
[DEBUG]  + WEB-INF/lib/mybatis-3.2.3.jar has been copied.
[DEBUG] Processing: mybatis-spring-1.2.1.jar
[DEBUG]  + WEB-INF/lib/mybatis-spring-1.2.1.jar has been copied.
[DEBUG] Processing: spring-data-jpa-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar
[DEBUG]  + WEB-INF/lib/spring-data-jpa-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar has been copied.
[DEBUG] Processing: spring-data-commons-1.6.3.RELEASE.jar
[DEBUG]  + WEB-INF/lib/spring-data-commons-1.6.3.RELEASE.jar has been copied.
[DEBUG] Processing: spring-orm-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar
[DEBUG]  + WEB-INF/lib/spring-orm-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar has been copied.
[DEBUG] Processing: spring-jdbc-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar
[DEBUG]  + WEB-INF/lib/spring-jdbc-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar has been copied.
[DEBUG] Processing: spring-tx-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar
[DEBUG]  + WEB-INF/lib/spring-tx-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar has been copied.
[DEBUG] Processing: spring-aspects-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar
[DEBUG]  + WEB-INF/lib/spring-aspects-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar has been copied.
[DEBUG] Processing: tomcat-jdbc-7.0.47.jar
[DEBUG]  + WEB-INF/lib/tomcat-jdbc-7.0.47.jar has been copied.
[DEBUG] Processing: tomcat-juli-7.0.47.jar
[DEBUG]  + WEB-INF/lib/tomcat-juli-7.0.47.jar has been copied.
[DEBUG] Processing: ojdbc6-11.2.0.1.0.jar
[DEBUG]  + WEB-INF/lib/ojdbc6-11.2.0.1.0.jar has been copied.
[DEBUG] Processing: spring-webmvc-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar
[DEBUG] Processing: spring-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar
[DEBUG]  + WEB-INF/lib/spring-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar has been copied.
```

Comment: Since you don't have versions specified, I'm guessing you will have `dependencyManagement` specified somewhere else? I would look if there is a `scope` defined in `dependencyManagement` section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've marked these dependencies as `optional`, which mean that other projects using this artifact have to decide for themselves if they explicitly add these dependencies or not. It seems they are required and not optional, so removing that tag will solve your problem.